# Unknown margin being added to a footer in IE6 + 7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, margin

So yeah, like I said, I've spent a few hours trying to fix this bug in the footer that add's an extra 20-30px on to the bottom of the page in IE6 and 7. I've currently set all bottom margins to 0 so as to find what's causing it, I then scoured ie developer tools but came up empty.

Here's the homepage design hosted on my web design playground - [Link](http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Softwear/)

Can anyone see the remedy?

Comment: 'Softwear' is consistently spelled incorrectly (Software). At least in English.

Comment: I didn't make the name, therefore not my typo, but I had noticed. Thank you hehe xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see:

```
/** FOOTER **/
#footer {
    margin: 40px 0 0px 0;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    background: url(images/footer.png) no-repeat top center;
    color: #404141;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Try changing the margin and padding to 0.

Comment: I have no idea how ie6 and 7 works, but removing the padding worked. However, I needed the padding, so that wasn't a solution. Googling for padding bugs in Ie6 and 7 returned a fix that was to simply add display:inline-block; to the css for that element, and it worked. Thanks for the help =)